# R Add new dataframe to existing table in SQL database (UPSERT)

Tags: sql, r, postgresql, upsert

I have a dataset stored as a table in a Postgres sql database i.e. `df_old`.
Now I want to add new data i.e. `df_new` and I want to update the existing table with them.
All data have a unique identifier (primary key), see column `id`.
If an `id` is already in the existing table, then this value should not be inserted. Otherwise insert all other values.
Here is my example code which creates the existing and the new data and already inserts the existing data in the Postgres SQL database:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(DBI)
library(RPostgres)
library(dbplyr)

# Create database connection
# You have to insert your own credentials for your own SQL database
con <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(), dbname = "mydatabase", ...)

# Create existing dataframe
df_old <- tribble(
  ~id, ~colA, ~colB, ~colC, ~colD,
  1, 23, 45, "Value g", 8,
  2, 67, 56, "Value h", 3,
  3, 26, 12, "Value w", 7,
  4, 98, 85, "Value h", 9
)

# Create existing table in database
dbWriteTable(con, "my_table", df_old, row.names = F)

# Create new dataframe
df_new <- tribble(
  ~id, ~colA, ~colB, ~colC, ~colD,
  2, 67, 56, "Value h", 3,
  5, 85, 56, "Value s", 5,
  6, 23, 16, "Value t", 2
)
```

Now I want to add the new values to the already existing database table.
However, I am stuck with the command that should add the values with the new ID's to the database table and ignore the values with the existing ID's.

Here is my desired output (updated table "my_table" in die SQL database):
The first value with id = 2 from the `df_new` was not inserted because this value already exists in the `df_old` table.

```
desired_df <- tbl(con, "my_table") %>% collect()

desired_df

     id  colA  colB colC     colD
1     1    23    45 Value g     8
2     2    67    56 Value h     3
3     3    26    12 Value w     7
4     4    98    85 Value h     9
5     5    85    56 Value s     5
6     6    23    16 Value t     2
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at [`dbplyr::rows_upsert()`](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/rows-db.html) and related functions, or [`dplyr::rows_upsert()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/rows.html) to do the same thing locally.

Comment: I have looked at the functions, but it is not clear to me how I can apply them in my case.

Answer (score 0):

After a long search I found a way to upsert. The `dbUpsert`-package provides the necessary function:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("timeddilation/dbUpsert")

library(dbUpsert)

dbUpsertTable(
  con,
  "my_table",
  df_new,
  "id")

# print the upserted table from the database
dbGetQuery(
  con,
  "SELECT * FROM my_table") %>% tibble()

     id  colA  colB colC     colD
1     1    23    45 Value g     8
2     2    67    56 Value h     3
3     3    26    12 Value w     7
4     4    98    85 Value h     9
5     5    85    56 Value s     5
6     6    23    16 Value t     2
```

However, the `dbUpsertTable`-function from the `dbUpsert`-package also has limitations.
Firstly, the package requires R >= 4.1.0.
Also there is no option about whether existing values should be updated or not, if the new dataframe contains different values for some columns.
The function simply overwrites the existing values with the new values.

Comment: Because of these limitations I do not mark this answer as "accepted" and would still appreciate an answer, at best using an official CRAN package.